# laravel 5.5 forge task scheduling cron job

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cron, forge

With older versions of Laravel I only had to write a command in Forges controlpanel eg `php /home/forge/default/artisan scheduled:run` then set the interval and hit schedule button.

Now in Laravel 5.5 I can se that I can add jobs in the kernel.php file eg:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('SomeJob:delete')
               ->daily();
    }
```

Does this mean I no longer have to setup cron jobs in laravel Forge?

Comment: You could use the kernel to schedule jobs before Laravel 5.5. But to answer your question, yes, you do still need to add the cron job within Forge in order to get any of your scheduled tasks to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need one cron entry to start the scheduler:

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```